# Handle packet loss using shell script in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sockets, network-programming

am trying to send the file contents using nc command in unix line by line to a port where the server is listening for further processing.

I am using the following code:

Client:

```
for inFile in `ls /home/dbadmin/input_data/*.dat`
do
        while read line
        do
                echo $line
                echo $line |nc -C 127.0.0.1 7870
        done<$inFile
done
```

In Server I have used the following command in while loop and it losses the some lines in that file. If I am sending the 70 lines, I am getting only 50 lines.

```
echo `nc -l 7870`
```

**Please give suggestions on how to solve this in Shell script (not using nc, if it is working with nc in diff way, I am okay for that) ?**

Comment: You're not specifying `-u`, so you're using TCP, and TCP does not lose packets.

Comment: So what is the problem here, Can you please elaborate?